The cursor of the textFormField is not in the right position when we write
I have a problem with a text field
This problem only occurs on the web on a smartphone (on the desktop everything is fine)
When I use the text field, it behaves strangely
The cursor is always placed on the second line of the text

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/test';
  Test({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        height: 200,
        child: TextFormField(
          maxLines: 10,
          cursorColor: Colors.brown,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

